# Proving the existence and number of *real* roots for $x^3 - 3x + 2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, roots

I need to find how many *real* roots this polynomial has and prove there existence. I was wondering if my logic and thought process was correct.

> Determine the number of *real* roots and prove it for $x^3 - 3x + 2$

First, note that $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$ and so

$f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$ and since $f'$ is strictly increasing on those intervals, there can be at most one root in each of them.

$f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and since $f'$ is strictly decreasing on this interval it can have at most one root.

Now examine $f(-3) = -16$ and $f(-1) = 4$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT) $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (-3, 1)$ and so $f$ has a root on the interval $(-\infty, 1)$.

Again examine $f(-1) = 4$ and $f(1) = 0$. We cannot say anything about $f$ having a root on the interval $(-1, 1)$.

Likewise examine $f(1) = 0$ and $f(3) = 16$. Again, we cannot say anything about $f$ having a root on $(1, \infty)$.

However, $f(1) = 1 - 3 + 2 = 0$ is clearly a root. And by factorizing the polynomial we get $f(x) = (x+2)(x-1)^2$. Indeed, $1$ is a root with a multiplicity of two.

Hence, $f(x)$ has two *real* roots.

---

***Additional Comments***

*Also, do we say two real roots (because of the multiplicity), or three real roots, or do we say two distinct real roots?*

*While I realize factoring the polynomial gives me the answer I believe the purpose of the question was to do the former analysis, which when the polynomial isn't easily factorized, can provide a lot of insight. That is why I did it all*

Comment: I assume you mean _real_ roots, because it has 3 complex roots.

Comment: _"First, note that $f′(x)=3x-3$ and so"_, you mean $f′(x)=3x^{\color{red}{2}}-3$...?

Comment: Haha yes! Let me make these adjustments.

Answer (score 5):

> However, $f(1) = 1 - 3 + 2 = 0$ is clearly a root. And by factorizing the polynomial we get $f(x) = (x+2)(x-1)^2$. Indeed, $1$ is a root with a multiplicity of two.

All the work you did before this becomes unnecessary; after factoring, the roots (and hence the *number of* roots) are clear - right?

---

Addition after some comments: when you are asked about the *number of roots* (real or not), it is usually meant to count the number of *distinct* (i.e. *different*) roots. Your equation has **two** (real) roots, one of which has multiplicity 2 but that doesn't change the fact that there are only *two real numbers* where the polynomial becomes 0.

Comment: Yes, but I think the purpose of the exercise was to do the former analysis. I only did that to show the multiplicity of the root. But yes in general all my work before would have been a waste haha!

Answer (score 1):

Since we have
$$
x^3-3x+2=(x-1)^2(x+2),
$$
we have three real roots $1,1,-2$. Here we count with multiplicities (which is standard for many results in geometry and other areas).

Comment: I would say there are *two* real roots, one of which has multiplicity two.

Comment: Yes, but I am suppose to do the little analysis before for the question I believe. Of course factoring would be much faster.

Comment: @danny Yes, this may be the case. But I think, it does not matter so much what you are *supposed* to do or think, but what you yourself think is the best way.

Comment: I agree with gandalf61. In the context of the fundamental theorem of algebra, we often say an $n$th-order polynomial "has $n$ complex roots" but this is an abbreviation where we mean to count the multiplicities. That doesn't change the fact that $x^3$ only has _one (distinct) root_.

Comment: This is also something I am not sure about, is it three real roots or two?

Comment: @danny see comment above; I would say yours has _two (distinct) roots_, we usually omit 'distinct' and mean _different roots_ when we're talking about the _number of roots_.

Comment: @StackTD I disagree, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function). But yes, usually the word "with multiplicity" is added, to make it really clear.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I would say that the derivative analysis would be the best way since in general I feel like we are interested in examining polynomials that are not easily factorized, but perhaps I am wrong. But in this case, factoring is certainly the best way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not sure how that wiki-page really disagrees with what I said... But to avoid confusion, it may be best to be explicit about it (in the question **and** in the answer).

Comment: @StackTD Yes, I am now explicit **also** in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3 - 3x + 2$

Possible roots are ±1 and ±2:

$f(1) = 1 - 3 + 2 = 0$

$f(2) = 8 - 6 + 2 = 4$

$f(-1) = (-1) - (-3) + 2 = 6$

$f(-2) = (-8) - (-6) + 2 = 0$

$x=1$ and $x=-2$ are the roots so we can factor the expression into $(x-1)(x+2)(x-1)$

We have the equation $(x-1)^2(x+2) = 0$

$(x-1)^2 = 0 \lor x + 2 = 0$

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = ±\sqrt{0} \lor x = -2$

$x-1 = ±0 \lor x = -2$

$x = 1±0 \lor x = -2$

$x = 1+0 \lor x = 1-0 \lor x = -2$

$x = 1 \lor x = 1 \lor x = -2$

The fundamental theorem of algebra says every polynomial of degree n has n roots. Since this polynomial is cubic, it has three roots. $x^3 - 3x + 2$ does have three real roots. It's just that two of them happened to be equal.